# Facebook photo feed

Tags: facebook, api, upload, photo

I was using FB api to post photos to my fanpage's news feed (http://www.facebook.com/MyApp/photos_stream), but from some time it stopped posting it to news feed and it just uploaded photos to some album (http://www.facebook.com/MyApp/photos).

This is the api command I was using before and after it was working, nothing has changed on my side.

```
$result = $facebook->api('/123456789/photos', 'post', $attrs);
```

So the question is, how to post photos to fanpage wall (timeline) properly and why it stopped working by itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few times ago.
In fact it was working but you have to go to your photo folder and accept the uploaded image.
In the album Facebook will show you a panel saying you have to approve those photos.
By doing this Facebook will publish the images on the timeline.

I know this is very annoying but I didn't find a better solution (I think Facebook has added a new security to avoid some abuses).

**EDIT:**
Look at the [Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos).

> You can post photos to a Page's Wall by issuing an HTTP POST request
>   to PAGE_ID/photos with the publish_stream and manage_pages permissions
>   and the following parameters.

Make sure you are using those two permissions and that your parameters are correct.

Comment: I don't see any approve option there :/

Comment: I was using the JavaScript SDK, but the process should be the same. What did you specify in $attrs?

Comment: I tried everything .. 'image', 'source', 'picture' and as a value relative path to image '@/images/image.jpg'. Everything with same result. It just upload the photo to album, but not timelime. I have all permissions.

Comment: Is 123456789 the same user as the one managing the application? I cannot find the source of the article, but I remember to read that images cannot be published on others timeline, they have to go to their image folder and then be approved. I know this is very bad to log on each time and approve all pictures, the only way to bypass this was to publish an article with a thumbnail.

Comment: 123456789 is not user, but fanpage ID that I am trying post to. As I said, i have token with every possible permission, so yes, publish_stream and manage_pages are there too. According to documentation, the only required parameter is 'source', but still it posts the photo just to the album, not timeline